# How to load custom chrome extension using selenium web driver in ruby?

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver

Is there any way that I could load custom chrome extension(is actually a folder of js files) when I execute selenium web driver?.

Comment: Its actually an unpacked extension.

Comment: what kind of extension it is? Can you run it in your browser with `URL` like `chrome-еxtension://just_sequence_of_symbols/addon_name.html` or it has its own GUI?

Comment: Well, I got the solution, pal. Anyhow thanks for the concern. Cheers

Comment: You actually can post your solution as answer to help other who could suffer from the same issue :)

Answer (score 3):

```
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, 
  :desired_capabilities => Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome({
    'chromeOptions' => {
      'extensions' => [
        Base64.strict_encode64(File.open('/Users/user/Downloads/hallway_extension.crx', 'rb').read)
      ]
    }
  })
```